# Loading modules with dependencies in Jasmine

Tags: javascript, angularjs, jasmine

I have a module that is defined as this:

```
var angular_multi_select_engine = angular.module('angular-multi-select-engine', [
    'angular-multi-select-constants'
]);
```

The `engine` depends on the `constants` module, as you can see.

I'm trying to run some tests on the `engine`, with this:

```
beforeEach(function() {
    angular.mock.module('angular-multi-select-engine', 'angular-multi-select-constants');
});
```

But when I try to run jasmine, it says:

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module angular-multi-select-engine due to:
[$injector:nomod] Module 'angular-multi-select-engine' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or forgot to load it. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies as the second argument.
```

If I try to load only the `constants` module, Jasmine works as expected and I can test the values of the `constants` module.

How should I load a module that has a dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out Jasmine is not loading the `engine` module because I have used ES6 syntax. I'll open a new question about that.